# Fill in a 2D array using a conditional

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, for-loop, nested-loops

[Year, TC_Number, Maximum wind speeds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtwqr.png)

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
'year': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
'TC_number': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'maximum_wind_speed': [20.37199783, 21.2, 21.7, 14.626, 18.108, 21.4, 25.3, 25.3, 22.9, 18.108, 20.2, 22.1, 24.3, 25.5, 27.7, 29.8, 33.6, 36.7, 36.6, 35, 33, 29.7, 29, 20]})
```

Hi All,

I've tried to find solutions by searching online, but, none seem to be what I am looking for.

I know what I want to do, but I am getting stuck on how to implement the code.

I first initialize a (1000, 240) array.
I then want to create a loop that fills in each row of the array.
Each row represents a single Tropical Cyclone (TC)'s recorded maximum wind speed values and 240 represents the maximum number of values that a TC could have. However, each TC will have varying number of values recorded in the maximum wind speeds row.
I want the loop to jump to the next row when the current TC number does not equal the previous TC number.

This is what I have so far:

```
output_array = np.full((1000, 240), np.nan)

#Shape of vmaxsyn is (337079,)

for i in range(1000):
    #print("i = ", i)
    for j in range(241):
        #print("j = ", j)
        name_id1 = df.iloc[j]['TC_number']
        name_id2 = df.iloc[j-1]['TC_number']
        
        if name_id1 == name_id2:
            output_array[i, j] = vmaxsyn[j]
            #print(output_array[j,i])
            #print([i,j])
        else: 
            #print("breaking out of inner loop")
            break 
#print("breaking out of outer loop.")
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
data = [
[20.372, 21.2, 21.7, 14.62, np.nan, np.nan],
[18.108, 21.4, 25.3, 25.3, 22.9, np.nan],
[18.108, 20.2, 22.1, 24.3, np.nan, np.nan],
[25.5, 27.1, 29.8, 33.6, np.nan, np.nan],
[36.7, 36.6, 35, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
[33, 29.7, 29, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]
```

The problem is none of the vmaxsyn values are being recorded to my output array. And I am also trying to deal with a broadcast error with my other approach. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm specifically trying to accomplish this with pandas.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for your response. I will do as you advised and edit my post. Sorry, first time here.

Comment: why are you using j when you set both `name_id1` and `namd_id2`? If you're only going to do that then won't you get the same answer no matter what's in the outer loop?

Comment: @ChrisSharp I was trying to use j in the inner loop to compare each TC_number. And when the TC_numbers are not equal to break to the outside loop to start a new row.

Comment: I understand but aren't you just doing the same thing 1000 times?

Comment: @ChrisSharp Oh, I see. Okay. I will see how to the fix that part. I guess that's where my troubles are coming from. Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisSharp Okay! This is better than what I started off with! Thank you. Values from vmaxsyn are being recorded into the 2D array. But, it isn't breaking to the next row. I guess that means my conditional is wrong. I will take a look at that now.

Comment: Make sure to get the first value before entering the 2nd loop. You only want to compare it to as few as possible of the 241 values. But one thing I haven't understood yet is why you're looping over the same data structure in both loops. Shouldn't one be a list of constants and the other your input data?

Comment: I guess the answer is I don't know how to loop over my input data. That's why I used 240 for the inner loop since I know that vmaxsyn should never exceed 240 values. I'm assuming that the loop would jump to the next row before the inner loop reaches 240. But, I am finding out now that my inner loop is only breaking because it is reaching 240.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop here at all. First, append one `id` column to your data which increments when `TC_number` changes. Then group your data by this newly created `id` and use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` for converting it in a list.

```
data['tc_id'] = data['TC_number'].ne(data['TC_number'].shift()).cumsum()-1

array = data.groupby('tc_id')['maximum_wind_speed'].apply(list)
```

The result will look like

```
print(array)

tc_id
0    [20.37199783, 21.2, 21.7, 14.626]
1     [18.108, 21.4, 25.3, 25.3, 22.9]
2           [18.108, 20.2, 22.1, 24.3]
3             [25.5, 27.7, 29.8, 33.6]
4                   [36.7, 36.6, 35.0]
5             [33.0, 29.7, 29.0, 20.0]
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Wow!! Would you happen to have some learning materials to know more about things like .ne(data['TC_number'].shift()).cumsum()-1? Thank you!

Comment: Indeed I would recommend stack overflow for learning such things. Search for questions similar to "How do I add a column to a data frame which increments by one every time its value changes?" and try to solve them, learn from the answers ...

Comment: I've since watched a pandas tutorial. I think I understand fully how your solution works. But, I think one thing I am still confused on is .cumsum()-1 . What does this part accomplish?

Comment: What you want to have is that all values corresponding to a `TC_number` go into one list entry. E.g. above `tc_id = 2` corresponds to `18.108, 20.2, ...`. For this, you have to enumerate `TC`. The first values (20.372, ..., 14.626) correspond to array entry 0, the next ones to 1 etc. For this enumeration you can't use `TC_number` from your data since `TC_number` has no ongoing enumeration. Therefore, I use `cumsum`. It increments by 1 if `TC_number` changes. So `TC_number` (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) would be mapped to (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2) (since I also use -1 for starting at 0).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand how your input / output arrays are but you can do something like that:

```
array = np.full((1000, 240), np.nan)    

last = None
i = 0
for tc_number, wind_speed in zip(tc_numbers_input, wind_speeds_input): # replace by your values
    if last != tc:
        i = 0
    last = tc
    array[tc][i] = speed
    i += 1
```

Using an array of size (10, 10) with the inputs you gave give this
(`print([list(x) for x in array])`)

```
[
    [20.37199783, 21.2, 21.7, 14.626, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
    [18.108, 21.4, 25.3, 25.3, 22.9, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
    [18.108, 20.2, 22.1, 24.3, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
    ...
]
```

Comment: This is awesome! I guess now I am wondering why it stopped at the 3rd row?

Comment: You didn't provide more informations

Comment: look at the dataframe you gave

Comment: Yikes! Sorry about that. I'm not sure why it got cut off. I corrected it. I'm gonna use your method.

Comment: It's weird that this is happening. I put in: 

    print("Last TC Number = ", last_tc_number)
    print("TC_number = ", tc_number)
    print("i = ", i)
    print(wind_speed)

and everything seems to be working, but only 3 rows are filled with values when I try to print out the entire array.

Comment: So, I am running into issues  array[tc_number][i] = wind_speed. The problem occurs when the tc_number resets to 0 upon starting a new year. I think this is why I am only getting 3 rows to print out.

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong since it does not take into that the `TC_number` in `data` is not consecutive. Furthermore, there are several undefined variables inside the `for` loop such as `tc`.